# Saving flash chart to png

Tags: javascript, flash, png

In Fusion charts 3.0 they have option to save the graph as PNG. But it is only for licensed users. But they don't have that option for free users. My requirement is to save it as an image somehow. Is it possible in the free version. To achieve that what am I supposed to do. Is there any mechanism (  3rd party tool ) to convert flash into PNG.

Thanks
`Shafi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: [DisplayObject to JPEG or PNG with IImageEncoder](http://blog.tsclausing.com/post/21)

Answer (score 1):

Use your OS's built-in screen capture facility.

- Windows: Alt+PrintScreen - captures to clipboard
- Mac OS X: Command+Ctrl+Shift+3 - captures to clipboard
- Mac OS X 10.4+: Command+Shift+4 - captures to PNG file on your desktop
- don't know about other platforms

After capturing to the clipboard, you can use almost any graphics app to save it as a PNG.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any screen shot tool: IrfanView (Options -> Capture) or SnagIt!

Answer (score 0):

Since FusionCharts Free is coded in Flash 6, you cannot directly export it to image. In FusionCharts v3 also, we make use of Flash 10 code (externally) as that provides us Byte Array needed to encode display bitmap into PNG. Without this, the only option we had till Flash 8 was to send it to server, which in turn decoded it. However, in FusionCharts Free we cannot even do that, as even bitmap access is not possible. As such, your only option is to use a client side tool that can save image.

Or, if you're using .NET, you can generate the chart on server, save as image and then use that. However, that is a bit processor intensive if you've to generate thousands of charts concurrently (as Flash objects need to be instantiated on server).

Cheers,
Pallav
FusionCharts Team